# How to view whether a task has completed?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have saved the following update query:

```
>>> self.es.update_by_query(body=body, doc_type='_doc', index='trackingesthistory', request_timeout=30, wait_for_completion=False)

{u'task': u'dEy4zO6jQuqs4wRV61t3Bw:8846674'}
```

Now how would I see if that task has finished or not? Here is what I've tried:

```
>>> elasticsearch.client.TasksClient.get('dEy4zO6jQuqs4wRV61t3Bw:8846674')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with TasksClient instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

What would be the correct way to get the Task status in python?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ElasticSearch client object to it, like so:

```
tasks = elasticsearch.client.TasksClient(self.es)
tasks.get('dEy4zO6jQuqs4wRV61t3Bw:8846674')
```

This will then give you the information needed.